# "ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)" but array sizes are the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]])

def np2dOperations(arr):
    a = arr[0:1]
    print(a)
    b = arr[1:2]
    print(b)
    c = arr[2:3]
    print(c)
    d = arr[3:4]
    print(d)
    e = np.matmul(a,c)
    print(e, "e")
    f = b*d
    x = e.sum()
    y = np.amax(f)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(x-y)
    return x-y

np2dOperations(arr)
```

my output:

```
[[1 1 2 2]]
[[1 1 2 2]]
[[3 3 4 4]]
[[3 3 4 4]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bethanne/Documents/NumPy2DOperations.py", line 24, in <module>
    np2dOperations(arr)
  File "/Users/bethanne/Documents/NumPy2DOperations.py", line 14, in np2dOperations
    e = np.matmul(a,c)
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

I keep getting the following error "ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (1,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)" even though arrays a and c are the same size. The result should be 16 from x-y. I tried using np.transpose on array a but that didn't work either. I am newer to programming with numpy and python so please explain what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to perform matrix multiplication, then you should be doing `np.matmul(a, c.T)` or `np.matmul(a.T,c)`. If you want an elementwise product, then you could just do `a*c` or `np.dot(a,c)`

Answer (score 0):

So you start with a 4x4 array:

```
In [17]: arr = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]])
In [18]: arr
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
In [19]: arr.shape
Out[19]: (4, 4)
```

Indexing with a slice retains the 2d shape:

```
In [20]: a = arr[0:1]
In [21]: a
Out[21]: array([[1, 1, 2, 2]])
In [22]: a.shape
Out[22]: (1, 4)
```

Indexing with a scalar reduces the dimensions by 1

```
In [23]: a1 = arr[0]
In [24]: a1
Out[24]: array([1, 1, 2, 2])
In [25]: a1.shape
Out[25]: (4,)
```

`matmul` for 1d arrays is clearly documented:

```
In [26]: np.matmul(arr[0],arr[1])
Out[26]: 10
In [27]: 
In [27]: np.matmul(arr[0],arr[2])
Out[27]: 22
```

`matmul` for 2d arrays is also clearly documented, and the requirements clearly stated in the error:

```
In [28]: np.matmul(arr[0:1],arr[2:3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-28-88ee2e80387e>", line 1, in <module>
    np.matmul(arr[0:1],arr[2:3])
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 4)
```

`matmul` of a (1,4) with a (4,1) does work, producing the same result as the 1d "dot" - except the result is a (1,1) array:

```
In [29]: np.matmul(arr[0:1],arr[2:3].T)
Out[29]: array([[22]])
```

Elementwise multiplication:

```
In [30]: arr[1]*arr[3]
Out[30]: array([3, 3, 8, 8])
In [31]: arr[1:2]*arr[3:4]
Out[31]: array([[3, 3, 8, 8]])
```

and so on for your other expressions.  In `numpy` there is a clear distinction between 1d arrays and 2d ones.  A (n,) shaped array is different from a (1,n) or (n,1) shape, even though they can be reshaped to each other.